# Python: Character combinations of 2 strings while maintaining position

Tags: python-3.x

I have two strings or lists with single characters and want to find out all possible combinations while
the positions of the characters in the original string/list should be maintained in the result.
The original strings/lists have the same length.

For example:

```
original_str1 = 'ABC'
original_str2 = 'DEF'

result = ['ABC','AEC','ABF','AEF','DBC','DEC','DBF','DEF']
```

So for position 1 only 'A' or 'D' is allowed, 'B' or 'E' for position 2 and 'C' or 'F' for position 3.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) may help you:

```
from itertools import product
result = [''.join(l) for l in product(*zip('ABC', 'DEF'))]
desired_output = ['ABC','AEC','ABF','AEF','DBC','DEC','DBF','DEF']
assert set(result) == set(desired_output)
```

Use standard library as much as you can. It is generally fast and well written and it will simplify your code.

Here's a simple timing test of stdlib vs clever pure Python code by [@trincot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39819401/847552) (I use [IPython](https://ipython.org/)):

```
In [1]: original_str1 = 'ABC'
   ...: original_str2 = 'DEF'
   ...: n = len(original_str1)
   ...: s = [original_str1, original_str2]
   ...:

In [2]: %timeit [''.join([s[(i>>j)&1][j] for j in range(0, n)]) for i in range(0, 2**n)]
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.8 µs per loop

In [3]: from itertools import product

In [4]: %timeit [''.join(l) for l in product(*zip('ABC', 'DEF'))]
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.62 µs per loop
```

As you can see, stdlib is about 4.5 times faster, and it's much easier to understand.

Comment: You could use `zip` to handle the rearrangement of the argument, e.g. `product(*zip(original_str1, original_str2))`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without itertools:

```
n = len(original_str1)
s = [original_str1, original_str2]

result = [''.join([s[(i>>j)&1][j] for j in range(0, n)]) for i in range(0, 2**n)]
```